# Does ros catkin build tool supports the target_compile_options

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to generate the LLVM bitcode for the ROS package. Tried to used the target_compile_options in the CMakeList.txt but it not emitting the llvm bitcode.

Is this option supported or not in the catkin build tool.

Note : Also as per the http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt the option is not supported. Just wanted to confirm regarding this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381565/does-ros-catkin-build-tool-supports-the-target_compile_options/) by [tareq97](https://answers.ros.org/users/71732/tareq97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin does not replace CMake.

Catkin only drives CMake (ie: starts it at the right moment).

So whatever the CMake version you use supports, you can use in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Catkin does not change anything there.

> Note : Also as per the http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt the option is not supported.

that page documents how the Catkin-contributed CMake *macros* should be used.

It does not say anything about whether or not certain CMake functionality is supported or not.

To make it extra clear: Catkin does not interpret nor execute your `CMakeLists.txt`. That's CMake's job. Catkin just starts CMake.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1